# Detecting Unicode Text in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I am storing bodies of text in SQL Server.

Some bodies of text contain Unicode characters that will be lost when storing in a `VARCHAR` column within SQL Server.

As only a small portion of text bodies stored will require a `NVARCHAR` column, I have decided to create 2 columns, one for `VARCHAR` text and the other a `NVARCHAR` text. This way I can save on space by only storing Unicode bodies of text in the `NVARCHAR` column and the rest in the `VARCHAR` column.

The question is: how do I detect if a body of text contains Unicode characters so that I can determine the best column to store it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either determine the 256 characters available in your collation's code page and inspect the string for any characters not in that set or cast it to `varchar` and then compare it to the `nvarchar` original.

If you are using code page 1252 then the first approach could be done with

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'൯'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN @String LIKE '%[^' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN + CHAR(0) + '-' + CHAR(255) + ']%'
           THEN 'varchar not OK'
         ELSE 'varchar OK'
       END
```

and the second approach...

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'൯'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN CAST(@String AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = @String
           THEN 'varchar OK'
         ELSE 'varchar not OK'
       END
```

BTW: If you use row compression you also get Unicode compression thrown in which would largely negate the need for this.

Comment: Using compression sounds like a preferable option, but I believe there is a limit on how large a fields can be compressed using the native SQL compression. I can potentially implement compression such as gzip using a SQL CLR library.

Comment: @EliPerpinyal row and page compression (which includes [unicode compression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835(v=sql.110).aspx)) only applies to data stored in row not large object data. SQL Server 2016 has a built in `COMPRESS` function for GZIP compression.